# Jupyter Lab not opening anymore

Tags: python, conda, jupyter-lab

Jupyter Notebook starts normally but when I try to start Jupyter Lab (either via cmd or conda prompt) I get the following error:

> Cannot open C:\Users\user\Miniconda3\envs\ds_env\Scripts\jupyter-lab-script.py

I checked and the "jupyter-lab-script.py" file is actually missing. It was working before but I think this happened after the last update.

How can I get it to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem got resolved on its own after installing another update.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that happened to me before with jupyter notebook and I re installed the whole anaconda navigator, seems that it just needed to be updated.

Answer (score 0):

open you terminal and type:

`pip install jupyterlab`

To open jupyter lab type:

`jupyter lab`

Do this again to reinstall/renew it